# how to stop a pod during helm upgrade

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

We have a deployment with different pods which are installed using helm install.
In the next release, one of the pods needs to be removed as it is obsoleted. How to stop the pod during helm upgrade ?
Thanks

Comment: Do you mean you have multiple Deployments, and one of them is no longer required?

Comment: helm does it for us automatically, when we run helm upgrade command unless, we have issues starting new pods.

Comment: Yes Dave, one of the POD is no longer required.

Comment: Do you have a bare Pod spec in your chart?  (If so, why?)  As @RipudamanSingh suggests, I'd expect just deleting the Deployment or Pod file from the `templates` directory and running `helm upgrade` to delete the corresponding objects from the cluster.  What have you tried already?  The Deployment/Pod/"stop"/"remove" is a little unclear here; can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

When you upgrade helm deployment it proceeds one by one. First, one pod is destroyed and created new pod with new changes if the upgraded deployment is successful and the new pod is running then it proceeds with the 2nd pod, and so on till the desired number of Pods is completed. If you still see an old pod running along with a newly upgraded pod it means something went wrong and the upgrade is not successful.
Run `kubectl get pods -n namespace` and check the ready state 1/1 or 2/2 if any container is not running or missing. If all the pods have the desired container and everything is okay then look for the logs by `kubectl logs -f pod --tail=10` and see if there is any log error. If all is okay then simply delete the old pod and if it is stuck in a terminating state then delete it by force like `kubectl delete pod <pod-name> --force --grace-period=0` This command will delete the old pod and keep the new pods.

Comment: The requirement is to remove the POD completely as it is obsoleted. No new POD needs to be spawned.

Comment: Just force delete as I mentioned.

Comment: Our is a product and we cannot do force delete.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the deployment descriptor will work. Helm during upgrade, deletes the POD if does not find  descriptor for any running pod.